# Applying a Curried Argument

Tags: scala

Given the following method:

```
scala> def f(x: Int, y: String) = x.toString + y
f: (x: Int, y: String)String
```

I can curry, getting a new method.

```
scala> f(55, _: String)
res8: String => String = <function1>
```

And then I can invoke the method with the curried argument:

```
scala> res8("foo")
res9: String = 55foo
```

But why can't I do this?

```
scala> f(55, _: String)("foo")
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("foo")
 required: Int
       f(55, _: String)("foo")
                        ^
```

Comment: I guess this becomes `(s:String) => (f(55,s)("foo"))` instead of `((s:String) => f(55,s))("foo")`.

Comment: @chi was my first thought, but OP is asking about much simpler thing - his function isn't curried

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses:

```
(f(55, _: String))("foo")
```